Tax Calculation Rounding issue in Admin order section. Could anyone please help?
We are facing a tax calculation rounding issue in my Magento Website (Version 2.4.4). We have tried many times but are unable to fix it. Could anyone please help? We have attached the screenshots for the tax configuration and order section. Please review them and provide a solution as soon as possible.



Can you check once item price, and total in the table 'sales order item'  in Magento doing rounding decimal 2-digit formatting it based on your tax calculation setting?
